# spark scala:Task not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This is a working code example:

```
case class log(log_version: String,log_ip: String,log_from: String,SDK: String,action_time: String,action: String,sn: String,fdn: String,typ: String,vid: String,version: String,device_id: String,ip: String,timestamp: String) extends serializable



val RDD = input.map{ line => 
    val p = line.split("\\|")
    val log_version = p(0)
    val log_ip = p(1)
    val log_from = p(2)
    val SDK = p(3)
    val action_time = p(4)
    val action = p(5)
    val sn = p(6)
    val JsonMap = if(p.length==8){
    val jsontest = parse(p(7), useBigDecimalForDouble = true)
    jsontest.extract[Map[String,String]]
    } else(Map("error" -> "empty"))
    val fdn:String = JsonMap.get("fdn").getOrElse("null")
    val typ:String = JsonMap.get("type").getOrElse("null")
    val vid:String = JsonMap.get("vid").getOrElse("null")
    val version:String = JsonMap.get("version").getOrElse("null")
    val device_id:String = JsonMap.get("device_id").getOrElse("null")
    val ip:String = JsonMap.get("ip").getOrElse("null")
    val timestamp:String = JsonMap.get("timestamp").getOrElse("null")
    log(log_version,log_ip,log_from,SDK,action_time,action,sn,fdn,typ,vid,version,device_id,ip,timestamp)}.toDF()
```

I am getting the following error whenever I try to access sc. What am I doing wrong here?

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
```

I change my code like this :

```
case class JsonLong(fdn:String,typ:String,vid:String,version:String,device_id:String,ip:String,timestamp:String)


case class log(log_version: String,log_ip: String,log_from: String,SDK: String,action_time: String,action: String,sn: String,JsonClass:JsonLong) extends serializable


val RDD = input.map{ line => 
    val p = line.split("\\|")
    val log_version = p(0)
    val log_ip = p(1)
    val log_from = p(2)
    val SDK = p(3)
    val action_time = p(4)
    val action = p(5)
    val sn = p(6)
    val JsonMap:JsonLong = if(p.length==8){
    val jsontest = parse(p(7), useBigDecimalForDouble = true)
    val x = jsontest.extract[Map[String,String]]
    JsonLong(x.get("fdn").getOrElse("NULL"),x.get("typ").getOrElse("NULL"),x.get("vid").getOrElse("NULL"),x.get("version").getOrElse("NULL"),x.get("fdn").getOrElse("NULL"),x.get("ip").getOrElse("NULL"),x.get("timestamp").getOrElse("NULL"))
    } else(null)
    log(log_version,log_ip,log_from,SDK,action_time,action,sn,JsonMap)}.toDF()
```

But I still get wrong? WHY? I don't get the point~~~Anyone who can tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark needs to be able to serialize the closure to send it to each executor. As a guess for what cannot be serlialized in your code, it looks like you are using json4s which needs an `implicit Formats` to extract the `Map[String, String]`. Try declaring the implicit within the map function.

Comment: Try extending `JsonLong` and `log` with `Serializable`. In scala the convention is naming classes with a capital so consider renaming `log` to `Log`.

Comment: also where is your `implicit val formats = DefaultFormats` (or whatever you are using for the case class serialization). This should be within the `map` function, that is what I meant in my answer.

Comment: I have 'implicit val formats = DefaultFormats ' in my code.I also tried extending JsonLong and log with Serializable, but still get same error.I'm sure the problem caused by class JsonLong. but I don't know why~~

Comment: move your `implicit val formats = DefaultFormats` to the line below `val RDD = input.map{ line =>`

Comment: I find the problem. that is caused by 'val jsontest = parse(p(7), useBigDecimalForDouble = true)
' when I change to use  JSON.parseFull(p(7) all become to right.But I still don't know why~~~

Comment: I also try your way that move {implicit val formats = DefaultFormats to the line below val RDD = input.map{ line =>} is also OK！！thanks！